# How to convert column of numbers to text separated by comma in set of four

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of 200 mobile numbers.
I want to convert these into rows of text in set of 4 mobile numbers and separated by comma.

```
12345678, 12345678, 12345678, 12345678
12345678, 12345678, 12345678, 12345678
12345678, 12345678, 12345678, 12345678
```

Please give me an advise.

Answer (score 2):

### Simple VBA macro to transpose a single column to multiple columns

[image]

I commented every step, so its easy to adjust the macro to your personal needs.
You can choose your data column and how many columns you want after transposing

1. Open Excel and VBA editor with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
2. On the left pane, paste the code under the *sheet* where your data is placed
3. Modify the first two lines according to your needs
4. Execute the macro with <kbd>F5</kbd>

---

```
Const strCol = "B"    '## select the column with your data
Const iTrans = 4      '## select how many columns you want after transposing

Sub transposeColumn()
    '## search the last row to know how many cells we have to iterate through
    iLastrow = Range(strCol & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    iCol = Range(strCol & 1).Column
    
    '## begin to loop through the chosen column
    '## Cause we delete cells on every loop, we need to divide the loop counter
    '## And since the division result isn't an integer, we have to round up
    For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(iLastrow / iTrans, 0)
    
        '## set the source and target range for easier access later
        Set rngSrc = Range(Cells(i + 1, iCol), Cells(i + iTrans - 1, iCol))
        Set rngTrg = Range(Cells(i, iCol + 1), Cells(i, iCol + iTrans - 1))
        
        '## set the format of target range to text
        rngTrg.NumberFormat = "@"
        
        '## copy and paste the values, the trick is to use transpose
        rngSrc.Copy
        rngTrg.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

        '## delete all cells which we have just transposed
        rngSrc.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: your macro swiftly convert the data into 4 excel columns.  It's great!  However, I need to convert them into text instead. Is it possible?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

An awk script will help with the problem.

The awk script's first for loop deals with the numbers up to the final multiple of four. The second loop prints the final few numbers. If it's the final number, the trailing comma is not printed.

```
awk '{ 
    for (n=1; n < NF-4; n+=4)
           printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", $n, $(n+1), $(n+2), $(n+3));    
    for (; n <= NF; n++)
        if (n == NF) 
            print $n;
        else 
            printf("%s, ", $n)          
}' filename
```

Comment: plse see my comments to nixda.  Is your macro converting excel data into text?  Also, how & where to put these scripts?

Comment: Oops didn't notice the excel tag, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here's a worksheet function solution. Where your list is in `A1:A40`:

```
=TEXT(INDEX($A$1:$A$40,(ROW()-1)*4+COLUMN()-2),"0000000000")
```

This is entered in `C1` and filled to the right to `F1` and then down as many rows as you need.

[image]

You will need to adjust the formula to match your sheet.

For example, if you want your output rows to start at `C2` instead, the second argument of the `INDEX` function should be `(ROW()-2)*4+COLUMN()-2`.

If you want your output rows to start at `D1` instead, the second argument of the `INDEX` function should be `(ROW()-1)*4+COLUMN()-3`.

**EDIT:**
I just saw that you wanted comma-separated output. This is a little hackish because `CONCATENATE` cannot take array arguments, but it will work. Just fill the following formula down a column.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(INDEX($A$1:$A$40,(ROW()-1)*4+1),"0000000000"),", ",TEXT(INDEX($A$1:$A$40,(ROW()-1)*4+2),"0000000000"),", ",TEXT(INDEX($A$1:$A$40,(ROW()-1)*4+3),"0000000000"),", ",TEXT(INDEX($A$1:$A$40,(ROW()-1)*4+4),"0000000000"))
```

This is dependent on your output starting in row 1. If, for example, your output starts at row 2 instead, you'll need to change each instance of `ROW()-1` to `ROW()-2`.

Comment: Um, comma-separated output? Now I'm not sure if I understand the OP right. I thought with "*I need to convert them into text*" he meant the cell format should be text. You think he wants them in a single cell?

Comment: @nixda See the title: "...convert column of mobile number to text separated by , in set of four". Easy to overlook. Anyhow, the sample output the OP gives seems to be exactly what is desired, not just a funky way of columnizing the data.